apex_page.get_url pass item value which have colon(:) delimited list
I use apex_page.get_url to prepare url in sql query in that way:
'javascript:window.open("'||apex_page.get_url(p_page=>'9', p_items=>'P9_A,P9_B,P9_C,P9_D,P9_E', 
p_values=> Z.COLUMN_VAL||','||:P8_B||','||:P8_C||','||:P8_D||','||:P8_E, 
p_clear_cache=> '9') ||'" ,"_blank")' as LINKDETAIL

but P8_D item is a checkbox and it have colon(:) delimited list so when I navigate through this URl values not pass properly of this item and the item next to it which P8_E so then I try to use with \P8_D\ but it gives syntax error on browser.
'javascript:window.open("'||apex_page.get_url(p_page=>'9', p_items=>'P9_A,P9_B,P9_C,P9_D,P9_E', 
p_values=> Z.COLUMN_VAL||','||:P8_B||','||:P8_C||','||'"\\"'||:P8_D||'"\\"'||','||:P8_E, 
p_clear_cache=> '9') ||'" ,"_blank")' as LINKDETAIL

but not work with this singe \ or double \. Please suggest what might be going wrong.

Try concatenating an extra colon after the multivalue item. Here is an example:
APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (
            p_page   => :APP_PAGE_ID,
            p_items  => 'P246_ENAME,P246_FAVORITE_DEPTS',
            p_values => :P246_ENAME||','||:P246_FAVORITE_DEPTS||':' )


It set multi value item perfectly but not set other items next to it.

You need to set the multivalue item as last one in the list. If you have > 1 multi value item this might not work. In that case you could use a workaround and replace the colons with an other separator value in your item. Then on the receiving page replace the new separator value back with colons.

In APEX 24.1 you can use define a different separator.

Done, now I place it at last in the list of all items and I have just one multi value item so it works. Thanks
